# Can't access the functions inside the code with the input menu

Tags: python, function, taskmanager

I cannot access the functions in the rest of the code in the input menu
The user is supposed to input a letter to which that letter will take him to the function of the program and continue editing as the function states, but I get an error message stating "NameError: name 'reg_user' is not defined".

```
def display_menu_options():    

    global menu_options

    menu_options = input('''Please select one of the following options:

a - Adding a task
va - View all tasks
vm - View my tasks
e - Exit
:''').lower()

    if menu_options == "a":
        add_task()
    elif menu_options == "va":
        view_all()
    elif menu_options == "vm":
        view_mine()
    elif menu_options == "e":
        print("Goodbye!")
    else:
        print("You have made a wrong choice, Please Try again")

    return menu_options

def display_admin_menu_options():

    global menu_options

    menu_options = input('''Please enter one of the following options:
    
r - register user
a - add task
va- view all tasks
vm - view my tasks
gr - generate reports
ds - display statistics
e - exit
:''').lower()

    if menu_options == "r":
        reg_user()
    elif menu_options == "a":
        add_task()
    elif menu_options == "va":
        view_all()
    elif menu_options == "vm":
        view_mine()
    elif menu_options == "gr":
        generate_reports()
    elif menu_options == "ds":
        all_statistics()
    elif menu_options == "e":
        print("Goodbye!")
    else:
        print("You have made a wrong choice, Please Try again")

    return menu_options

def login():

    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")

    for line in open('user.txt', 'r').readlines():
        field = line.strip().split(", ")
        if username == field[0] and password == field[1]:
            print('Welcome' + username)
            return True, field[0] == "admin"

    return False, False

login_success, is_admin = login()

if login_success and is_admin:
    display_admin_menu_options()
elif login_success:
    display_menu_options()
else:
    print("Username or password incorrect!")
```

Comment: Soooo... have you written a function called `reg_user()`?

Comment: Yes I have a reg_user function and more functions after the snippets. The snippets is the beginning of the code where as the program would run first to see if the username is 'admin' or another username. All my functions are written out, but I can't access them from the input menu (when user enters "r", it should jump to that function).

Comment: Functions need to be defined *before* they're called in the code. This is different from some other programming languages. I'd recommend writing a core `main()` function, then put your utility functions, then call `main()` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are executing and writing it as a script. Therefore you're calling the function and beneath your defining the functions you're trying to access. Those are not "defined" because the code is interpreted and not compiled. Put all function definitions above the login() call